# Hook problems when using @fluentui/react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fluentui-react

I'm trying to use the Link component in @fluentui/react, but I get an error about invalid hook calls.  I tried using Link in office-ui-fabric-react, but got same hook error.

**Background:**

Component A calls the code with the Link component.

Component A is in a different folder than Link component.

**Error:**
"react-dom.development.js:3198 Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

**Link code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Link } from "@fluentui/react";
//import { Link } from "office-ui-fabric-react";

export interface ITestProps {
  what: string;
  click: () => void;
}

export default class TestComponent extends React.PureComponent<ITestProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: ITestProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Test {this.props.what}
        <button onClick={this.props.click}>Click</button>
        <Link onClick={this.props.click}>Click link</Link> <-- this is what is causing hook problems
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then I tried using a functional component rather than extending from React.PureComponent, but same hook error:

```
export default function TestComponent(props: ITestProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      Test2 {props.what}
      <button onClick={props.click}>Click</button>
      <Link onClick={props.click}>Click link</Link> <-- also produces hook error
    </div>
  );
}
```

The ***only*** way that I solved this problem is my Link code inside the ***same*** folder as the Component that uses the Link code.

I want to be able to put my Link code in a *separate* folder, ***not*** in the same folder as Component A.

I also made sure that the react and react-dom version of *both* folders are the same, but I still got hook errors.

**Please any suggestions?**

Comment: Make sure you have only one package.json